PreferenceFragment Activity toolbar
In a Compose application, I implemented the Settings screen as a new AppCompatActivity containing my PreferenceFragment.
In order to navigate between screens in Compose and the Preference Activity, I use intents.
I added a Toolbar with a left arrow icon to the AppCompatActivity, not linked to any NavController:
Settings Activity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ... // replace content view with PreferenceFragment
    val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)) 
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}

Layout of Settings Activity
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_24"
        app:title="@string/settings" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>

This approach works, but has 2 problems:

The toolbar is all clickable, whilst I would like to have only the left arrow navigation icon clickable
The left arrow navigation icon should have the ripple effect


Since this is a specific requirement, you could inherit the MaterialToolbar provided by the package and make changes accordingly

Adding setNavigationOnClickListener for toolbar will stop toolbar for getting clicked so, remaining part of the toolbar will not be clickable, and the user will be able to only click on the icon for navigation. Also this will show ripple effect for the navigation icon.

You can try this below code :
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)

        //This line is important else listener won't work
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar) 
        
        // Enable back navigation icon
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        
        // Set click listener for navigation icon
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
        }


        // When user selects a menu item
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_settings -> {
                    // Navigate to settings screen.
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_done -> {
                    // Save profile changes.
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }


    }
}

Reference link :

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#nav-icon

